# Is there a website to minimize overall agony for N travelers at once?

Tags: air-travel, usa, planning, business-travel

Suppose I have 4-7 people in different cities around the US. They need to meet, doesn't matter where as long as there is a reasonable hotel with a conference room. Is there a website or method to determine the best central city to meet in? A city which minimizes the overall agony (cost + time + layovers) of all participants at once.

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  Somehow [WebEx](http://www.webex.com) seems more appropriate as a solution for this dilemma.

Comment: I would just pick one of the people to act as host. You have someone who knows it and can properly arrange things locally.

Comment: @Philip What about video conferencing ?

Comment: We do voice-only conferences daily. Have not tried video but plan to. Still meeting in person once or twice a year I think is a good idea. Having one person host instead of going someone in the middle does make some sense. Thanks for ideas.

Comment: I disagree with the close votes.  This is very much a travel question, no less than the *travelling salesman* is; it's about minimising travel time and cost considering boundary conditions.  For a single participant A->B travel, many websites exist.  Asking for methods on how to solve the problem described in the question is travel-related.

Comment: Changed question to be more specific, less subjective. Seems like a very concrete question and certainly 100% travel related because it's entirely about navigating airline routes and fares.

Comment: @gerrit Which makes it a math or CS question rather then a travel question per-se.

Comment: I agree with @gerrit. It's in fact a Math problem but in  the real world where the shortest path is not necessarily the minimal cost or the quickest travel. It's a mix of everything and you have to get values. There could exist a website that, given a group of cities, searched for the cheapest flights with connections for every other city. I do it all the time (N = 1). Someone else asked the same here for N = 2 (http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13845/how-do-i-minimize-total-cost-of-separate-flights-to-the-same-destination-plus-op). How different is asking the same for  N >= 2 ?

Comment: Well, changing the question in this way makes my answer totally irrelevant. What's the etiquette here?

Comment: @choster: Your answer is not that irrelevant, but with Philip's permission, I'd roll back the question to its previous form. Generally, changing the question context is frowned upon, particularly when there are already answers which are to be rendered obsolete.

Comment: Yes [this](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13845) is a subset, but it has no accepted answer. The correct answer to all these questions is "no". It's not a math question; how to *create* a website like this is a math question, but "is there a website" is travel related with a simple the answer "no", I have come to learn. But yes please rollback or close or both, whatever is best for the archive. Choster gave some helpful *related* tips which imply that there's no better way to do this, so I could accept it and I'll add the comment "this means no" I think that's the best outcome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If for some reason you can't do an online meeting or conference call, I have three tips for planning a **business meeting** (*not* a conference or a vacation, where flight convenience is not the controlling factor).

### Know your group

When dealing with business travel, it's important to remember that the ticket price is not the only cost incurred; time is also significant, especially in case of irregular operations. If you're choosing between two airports, pick one that is a hub for whichever airline the most members of your group have frequent flyer elite status with. The elite status means less time waiting in line and priority service if something goes wrong, especially if one has a lounge membership. Ultra-discount airlines, on the other hand, are right out.

### Minimize connections

Assuming your group is more concerned about time and convenience than about cost, I would argue the most important thing to avoid for an important business meeting is a connection.

- On any given flight, you could have weather delays, mechanical problems, missing crew members, air traffic congestion, and so on. When you have two flights, you double the number of times you can experience any of these things, and if they occur on your first segment, you could miss your second segment and end up delayed by hours or even days. On top of this, there is a risk of getting lost at the connection point (for example, if there is a terminal change from one airline to a partner airline), and any checked bags are also far more likely to get misplaced or misrouted during a connection than on a nonstop.
- Each stop entails additional time, because your aircraft goes through an extra takeoff and landing cycle plus up to an hour for servicing (cleaning, restocking, refueling, etc.). And depending on the route, the hub may be out of the way, forcing you to backtrack at least partially, which also eats up time (Delta likes to send me BWI-ATL-MCI, almost half again as long as BWI-CVG-MCI would be).

Nonstops do command a premium, but that's because they're often worth it for business travel. So I would aim for a city which has nonstop service from the airports where the various group members will be flying out of. Depending on the particular distribution of your group, this is most likely to be a relatively hub of one of the Big 3 (United, Delta, American), but it could just as easily be a focus city for Southwest, which offers frequent nonstops from medium-sized cities.

Most major airlines have an interactive route maps on their website, which will help you visualize service to and from a particular airport.

### Schedule well

On the ground, most things will balance out. Every major airport will have some business class hotel nearby with adequate meeting facilities, mediocre food, and a free shuttle from the terminal. The cost will vary depending on the location, but the cost of the room rental will probably be far below the cost of the flights anyway.

But schedule well, both time of year and time of day. San Francisco sees many fog delays in the summer, while Miami gets overwhelmed during winter holidays. Philadelphia gets delays for no good reason all the time. Flight delays cascade throughout the system and compound through the day: when an incoming flight is delayed, it is often delayed in departing again. The first flight of the day, having had all night to arrive and undergo maintenance, is far less likely to see a delay. So don't schedule a dinner meeting in Chicago in August and expect to have everyone there on the dot.

Comment: The answer it seems is "no". There is no website that can do this calculation for you.  But these are some good tips to consider when picking a city manually, so I'm accepting this as the best answer.