# Find the top k cheapest airports to meet for two people departing from different airports

Tags: air-travel, tickets, online-resources, flight-search-engines

I'm looking for a way to find the top k cheapest airports to meet for two people departing from two different airports, and given some dates. The meeting airport shouldn't be the same as one of the two departing airports. Which flight search engine has this feature?

Comment: Maybe [tripmatch](https://www.tripmatch.org/#/)?

Comment: I'd be happy to get some feedback from the downvoters.

Comment: Close voters: that's not a WANTA question.

Comment: What is "k" in this question? Is that like top `n` or top `x`? Or does it mean something more specific?

Comment: @Midavalo yes, like top n or top x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coming a bit late to the discussion, but a similar search engine is [flightsmeet.io](https://www.flightsmeet.io), which gives you more control over choosing the inbound and outbound flights.

Search form:

[image]

Result example:

[image]

Disclosure: I am the creator of FlightsMeets.

Answer (score 2):

As [mkennedy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/465/mkennedy) commented, the flight search engine https://www.tripmatch.org/ has this feature:

[image]

Can also specify flight duration and departure/arrival time windows:

[image]
[image]

Example of results:

[image]

Doesn't seem to work well for some international flight routes.

Answer (score 2):

The flight search engine [PanFlights](https://panflights.com/meet) offers flights meetup functionality.

Attaching screenshot with the search box.

Disclosure: I am the founder of PanFlights.

[image: PanFlights Meet search interface]